# How does E show that these vectors are linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, vectors

This is the question I

I just started learning matrices and we haven't done anything like this before, I don't know how I'm supposed to show that these four vectors are linearly dependent.

Vectors are a(1,0,0) b(1,-1,0) c(0,1,-1) d(0,3,-2) (column form)

Comment: Show that there is some linear combination of these with at least some non-zero coefficients such that the combination is equal to the zero vector.  Equivalently, show that one of these is able to be written as a linear combination of the others.

Comment: Since this is your first time encountering a problem like this, you should absolutely go about this by first principles... approaching directly via the definitions.  Once you have developed some understanding and intuition and have proven some theorems related to this you can take shortcuts.  For instance, it is very well known that if you have $m$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional space where $m>n$ then those $m$ vectors must necessarily be linearly dependent, making the answer here immediately obvious.  I emphasize, you should *not* use this result right now.

Answer (score 1):

A collection of vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots, v_n$ are said to be linearly dependent iff there exists some choice of scalar coefficients $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n$ with at least one of these coefficients nonzero such that $\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\dots+\alpha_nv_n$ is equal to the zero vector.

A collection of vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots,v_n$ are said to be linearly independent iff the *only* choice of coefficients $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n$ which result in $\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\dots+\alpha_nv_n=0$ is where $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\dots=\alpha_n=0$.

(*Note, $\alpha_1=\dots=\alpha_n=0$ is always a solution.  The question is whether or not it is the only solution or if other solutions exist*)

For your question, we ask... are there coefficients $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4$ with at least some nonzero such that $\alpha_1\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+\alpha_2\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}+\alpha_3\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}+\alpha_4\begin{pmatrix}0\\3\\-2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$

> Indeed, yes there are (*as expected*).  Letting $\alpha_1 = -1, \alpha_2=1, \alpha_3=-2, \alpha_4=1$ we can verify the sum does in fact result in the zero vector and so the vectors are indeed linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, as a result they are necessarily linearly dependent.

Comment: Although true, this is not helpful to the OP.  The OP needs to understand basic definitions and how to use those basic definitions before they should move forward to theorems which they are not ready for.